# Proper way to cite R help?

Tags: r

I want to cite the R help description of a function. Is there a proper way to cite the R help? Or should I simply cite the package of the function?

Comment: Anything citeable in the R help is probably itself essentially material from the citations in the package manual (or even in some cases from the very help page itself)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cite the package.

The citation information for a package can be found with `citation(libraryName)`.

If you wanted to go into a lot of detail, you could list out the main function(s) you used from the package. But going as far as citing the actual help file for a function is going a little far (unless this help file really contributed to the literature, i.e. included a novel proof or something).